# Firebase Cloud Messaging iOS application, getFrom Android equivalent?

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

On Firebase Messaging, when receives a message on Android application, exists a getFrom method (remoteMessage.getFrom()) to know who sends the message. Exists an equivalent on iOS?

Comment: Love the Yoda talk.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your response

Answer (score 0):

There is no iOS counterpart for the [RemoteMessage.getFrom()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html#getFrom()) method in Android.

For iOS, when [handling messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive#handle_messages), instead of a `RemoteMessage`, you receive *a dictionary of keys and values*, which is received in your `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

A workaround you can do in order for you to know which sender the message is from, is for you to include a custom key-value data for the sender ID (e.g. `sender_id`=`<Sender ID here>`) in your data payload. For more details in handling messages in iOS (and Android), you can refer to the [FCM Official Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).